# Pulling data from Azure SQL database into an Excel through a parameterised stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure, stored-procedures

I have data in an Azure SQL database, which I would like to pull into an Excel sheet through the use of stored procedure(s) which require parameters.

However, I'm struggling to do this, as I cannot get it to work how it works with a local SQL server. Ordinarily this is done through Microsoft Query, defining the connection to the database, and entering `{ CALL sproc (?) }` and then using the Connections command to map a cell to the parameter.

I cannot set up a connection to the database in MS Query. When I enter the `xxx.database.windows.net` as the server, my username / password, and then try to switch to database I need to use I get the message below

> Filling listbox failed:
>
> SQLState: '37000'
>
> SQL Server Error: 40511
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Built-in function 'has_dbaccess' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Can anyone offer any assistance please?

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file with the .DSN extension then add content like the following into it...

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
SERVER=xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1234
APP=Microsoft Office 2010
WSID=NA
DATABASE=DB12345
[Microsoft Office]
UID=myUsername
PWD=myPassword
```

You can then just use this connection from Microsoft Query without dealing with the dialogs that are giving you grief.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out with a combination of Youtube videos and dumb luck lol. You have to create an OBDC connection with Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server (or higher.) Make sure you connect and define the correct database in the ODBC object while entering in your Azure SQL connection info. Once that's done from within excel you can use MS Query to select that ODBC object and pull the data as you normally would.