# SQL Server Login required in Excel when refreshing Azure database

Tags: excel, azure

I have a SQL database on my Azure server that I connected to in Excel. When I try refreshing the connection in Excel it requires me to enter my login/password for the server:

[image]

Can I remove this requirement? I want to share this file with friends, but don't want to require a password.

Thanks!

Comment: Then you'll have to save the password within the Excel file. But the password won't get encrypted and can be read by any user in clear text: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/277600 OR using this solution (with a connection file) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245383/pulling-data-from-azure-sql-database-into-an-excel-through-a-parameterised-store

Comment: @Ralph Great, thanks for the resources! I will check out the first option.